# Which oracle session variable controls varchar2 'fitting' to table column?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am observe strange behavior that I can't explain:

SP that inserts rows into the global temporal table raise an error 'value to large for column' when it is called from Oracle Developer.

The same time this SP works fine when it is called from application.

The quick searching of Oracle documentation doesn't  give me any idea what kind of session level variable could be responsible for such things. Please point me missed doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason of such kind of problems NLS-dependent implicit conversions can be.
Example below shows how can you get such error then you pass DATE as a paramenet while column type is VARCHAR2:

```
SQL> create global temporary table d_tab (x varchar2(8))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure d_ins
  2  (
  3    p_x in date
  4  )
  5  is
  6  begin
  7     insert into d_tab values(p_x);
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYYMMDD';

Session altered.

SQL> exec d_ins(sysdate)

Pl/SQL prcoedure completed.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL> exec d_ins(sysdate)
BEGIN d_ins(sysdate); END;

*
error in line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column string (actual: 10, maximum: 8)
ORA-06512: in  "SCOTT.D_INS", line 7 
ORA-06512: in  line 1
```

P.S. Also, the problem can be when you specify the column length in BYTE (by defaul) while you are using Unicode charset where a symbol can take more than 1 byte. So change the definition of your column to VARCHAR2(... CHAR) and look at the result.

Seems you are using national language values, so this can lead to inconsistency (I used Russian character in example below):

```
SQL> create table t1 (x varchar2(1 byte));

Table created.

SQL> select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

VALUE                                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AL32UTF8                                                                        

SQL> insert into t1 values('А');
insert into t1 values('А')
                      *
error in line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCOTT."T1"."X" string (actual: 2, maximum: 1)

SQL> alter table t1 modify (x varchar2(1 char));

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t1 values('A');

1 row inserted.
```

Comment: Very subtle, thank you:) Unfortunately this is not my case: my SP passes varchar2(9) to varchar2(6) ...

Comment: Could you please provode more details in post - table structure, procedure, test case ?

Comment: This is the problem that can be solved only 'theoretically': otherwise I would need to share application server what is too complex. As I said just trying to insert raise an error. Calling from app server - works. But I can guarantee that both calls parameters are the same and the call of this sp throwgh app server was really done (there are log entries). If there are no such session parameters that means app server session somehow use "another" data (e.g. locked the snapshot at the moment where there was no 'long values')...

Comment: Please see new example above - this can be related bu the character set  fetaures.

Comment: You are guru! Another subtle idea. It is also not the my case. Source  table field just contains 8 and 9 characters strings and sp wants to pack it to nvarchar(6). I will work on my 'app server used another data' explanation. First-quick fact: v$lock doesn't contain source field's table...

Comment: There is something that I do not predict in global temporal tables behaviours. :( SQL Devloper and Application Server uses the same global table but SELECT from it can return different result. I see that application server locks it. And may be cashe it..

Comment: This is expected behavior when you use temporary tables (if I got your point correct). Every session has it's own instance of temporary data in such table which other sessions can not access and they don't see. Every session takes normal TM lock on temporary table in dictionary to prevent any ALTER command over it - exactly like for ordinar table.